# Which of the following define a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Which of the following define a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

$d_1(x,y) = \frac{|x|-|y|} {1+|x||y|}$

$d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$

$d_3(x,y) = |f(x)-g(x)|$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotonic increasing function.

Here is my attempt:

$d_1(x,y)$ satisfies all the three conditions.

$d_2(x,y)$ may fail to satisfy triangle inequality.

$d_3(x,y)$ is not a well defined function.

I am not sure whether i am correct or not? I need a proper justifications.

Thanks for giving me time.

Comment: Note that $d_{1}(-1,1)=0$.

Comment: @ThomasE. Great comment. Simple and elegant.

Comment: @srijan What is $g$?$g$ is not in the question. Isn't it $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|?$. isn't it a question of NBHM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re certainly right about $d_3$, since we’re told absolutely nothing about $g$.

To show that $d_2$ may fail to satisfy the triangle inequality, you need to produce an actual example of such a failure. What if $x=0,y=1/2$, and $z=1$?

You need to take another look at $d_1$: what if $|x|<|y|$?

Comment: if we have $d_1(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|} {1+|x||y|}$ , can we say that it will form metric space?

Comment: @srijan: What happens if $x=0,y=1,z=2$? Does the triangle inequality hold for all permutations of those three points?

Comment: Certainly it will not satisfy triangle inequality for $x = 0$, $y = 2$, $z = 1$. Heartily thanks to you sir.

Comment: One last question sir: What if g is also strictly monotonically increasing function?

Comment: @srijan: And $d_3(x,y)=|f(x)-g(y)|$? It won’t satisfy $d_3(x,x)=0$ for all $x$ unless $f=g$.

Comment: @Brain Thanks again sir. Now things are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

It was recently [pointed out in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15201/2017/10/25) that $d(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$ in fact is a metric. (I am posting this answer mainly so that incorrect - or at least vague - information in the accepted answer is somewhat less prominent.)

See also some other related posts:

- [Is $d(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$ a metric on R?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707468/is-dx-y-sqrtx-y-a-metric-on-r)
- [Proof of triangle inequality for $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\lvert x-y\rvert}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738024/proof-of-triangle-inequality-for-dx-y-sqrt-lvert-x-y-rvert)
- [How do I prove that $d(x,y)=(|x-y|)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583415/how-do-i-prove-that-dx-y-x-y-frac12-is-a-metric)
- [do the following define a metric on $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658255/do-the-following-define-a-metric-on-r)