# How do I prove that $d(x,y)=(|x-y|)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a metric?

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric defined by $$d(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$$

where $x, y\in X$.

> How do I prove the triangle inequality for the metric $d(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$?

Comment: Does $|x-y|$ itself form metric?

Comment: You show that $d$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Carefully show that it satisfies the conditions for a metric.

Comment: Perhaps $X$ is the real line?  Or some other place that absolute value is defined?

Comment: See also: [Is $d(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$ a metric on R?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/707468)

Answer (score 4):

We can appeal to properties of square roots in $\mathbb{R}$, namely for all positive $x$ and $y$, $\sqrt{x + y} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$.

It follows then that, for $x,y,z \in X$,

$\begin{align*}
(|x - z|)^{1/2} &= (|x-y + y-z|)^{1/2} \\
&\leq (|x-y| + |y-z|)^{1/2} \\
&\leq (|x-y|)^{1/2} + (|y-z|)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 2):

$$
d(x,y) \leq d(y,z) + d(x, z) \iff \text{ (square both sides) } \\
|x-y| \leq |y-z| + |x - z| + 2\sqrt{|x - z||y-z|}
$$

which is true since $|x-y|$ satisfies the triangle inequality and $2 \sqrt{|x-z||y-z|}$ is a positive number.  So you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Note your $X=\mathbb{R}$. So for $x,y\geq 0$, we have 
$x+y\leq x+y+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}=(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2$. Hence we obtain $\sqrt{x+y}\leq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}.$