# Show that $|e^{-|x-y|}-1|$ is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that $d(x,y)=|e^{-|x-y|}-1|$ is a metric, I already went throught the first 3 steps, but I'm having trouble with the triangular inequality, as far as i know is not possible to get $|e^{-|x-y|}-1|\leq |e^{-|x-z|}-1|+|e^{-|z-y|}-1|$ thanks for your help

Comment: Nice visualization https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6nry3chr9c, there are no points both red and green (since green shape is open) so the green equation should be $\ge k$.

Comment: Nice way to see it, thanks

Comment: [Abstractly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707468/is-dx-y-sqrtx-y-a-metric-on-r), the function $f(t) = 1 - e^{-|t|}$ is $0$ at $0$, and is increasing and concave on the non-negative reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $e^x\le1$ for all $x\le0$.

$$\begin{aligned}&\quad |e^{-|x-z|}-1|+|e^{-|z-y|}-1| - (|e^{-|x-y|}-1|) \\
&= 1-e^{-|x-z|}+ 1 - e^{-|z-y|} - (1- e^{-|x-y|})\\
&= 1-e^{-|x-z|} - e^{-|z-y|} +e^{-|x-y|}\\
&\ge 1-e^{-|x-z|}- e^{-|z-y|} +e^{-(|x-z| + |z-y|)}\\
&=(1-e^{-|x-z|})(1 - e^{-|z-y|})\\
& \ge0
\end{aligned}$$
The first inequality holds since $|x-y|=|(x-z ) + (z-y)|\le |x-z| + |z-y|$ and the function $f(x)=e^x$ is an increasing function.